# Why doesn't my multiply SQL work, says not a group by expression

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, multiplication

Can someone please explain why this does not work:

```
select
   supplierorder,
   company,
   forename,
   surname,
   telephone,
   order_date,
   lbs_items.name,
   price,
   quantity,
   sum (quantity * price) as "Order Total Price:"
from
   lbs_supplier_orders
   join lbs_suppliers using (supplier)
   join lbs_persons using (person)
   join lbs_addresses using (address)
   join lbs_supplier_orderlines using (supplierorder)
   join lbs_items using (item)
group by
   supplierorder
```

Comment: without seeing any of your data structure one can only hazard a guess; each row of data is distinct, don't use `group by` and see what happens.

Comment: When aggregating (you're using SUM) you have to group by all of the columns in the select list in which you are not aggregating. (company, forename, etc.)

Comment: I've tried it without the group by and it still doesn't work, is there a quick way I can show the data structure?

Answer (score 4):

In an aggregation query, all columns either need to be in the `group by` clause or in aggregation functions (such as `sum()` or `avg()`.  I think you intend something like:

```
select supplierorder, company, forename, surname, telephone, order_date,
       sum(quantity * price) as "Order Total Price:"
from
   lbs_supplier_orders
   join lbs_suppliers using (supplier)
   join lbs_persons using (person)
   join lbs_addresses using (address)
   join lbs_supplier_orderlines using (supplierorder)
   join lbs_items using (item)
group by supplierorder, company, forename, surname, telephone, order_date;
```

Notice that I removed some columns.  If you include all possible columns, then I wonder why you need an aggregation query.

Comment: Thank you! Worked first time!

Comment: If the answer solved your question and you came back commenting that it resolved your issue; why wouldn't you mark it as the accepted answer?